# CSS: How to add multiple selectors (one of them is [attribute*=value]) using :not

Tags: css, label

Tried to select those label which classes != .control-label, *=' text-', but failed.

For example shown below, i want "0.00" to be set as color=#000f1d, but it falls into color:#000 (body)

---

Updated again with working version, with Bolt's help, figured out that I'm missing :not()<--- bracket! (and missing )

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

.control-label {
  color: blue;
}

.text-danger {
  color: red;
}

form label:not([class*='text-']):not(.control-label) {
  color: #000f1d;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 control-label">Sample</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">0.00</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-danger">Non-Qualified</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Missing a set of parens around the first :not.

Comment: @ObsidianAge yap, just update with an example

Comment: @BoltClock Can you shows an example? thanks.

Comment: form label:not([class*=' text-']):not(.control-label) The same way you put parens around .control-label.

Comment: BTW, your example is missing a form element so even with the correct selector you won't see the correct output here.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, it works! My fault, not checking it thoroughly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Your snippet does not include a `<form>`, so your initial `form` selector won't match.
- You're missing the brackets around the first `:not`. You want `:not([class*=' text-'])`.

Ultimately, you're looking for `label:not([class*=' text-']):not(.control-label)`:

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

.control-label {
  color: blue;
}

.text-danger {
  color: red;
}

label:not([class*=' text-']):not(.control-label) {
  color: #000f1d;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 control-label">Sample</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">0.00</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-danger">Non-Qualified</label>
</div>
```

Note that this has higher specificity than your `.text-danger` selector, so will also change the colour of your 'Non-qualifed' element. If this is not desired, simply add more specificity to that selector:

```css
body {
  color: #000;
}

.control-label {
  color: blue;
}

label:not([class*=' text-']):not(.control-label).text-danger {
  color: red;
}

label:not([class*=' text-']):not(.control-label) {
  color: #000f1d;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 control-label">Sample</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">0.00</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="text-danger">Non-Qualified</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, was not aware missing <form> on the sample given, updated it, and it works! Thanks again for helping